# Is String Builder or ""+someNumb more efficient/correct for small cases?

Tags: java, android

II've been in the habit of doing:

```
int num = 12;
String text = ""+12;
```

for a long time, but I've found that to be a very inefficient mechanism for the large number of additions.

For those cases I generally do something like:

```
// this is psuedo code here..
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fis);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while(input.hasNext()) {
   builder.append(input.nextString());
}
```

My question is:  When coding for Android (vs the General Java case) Is the performance trade off at the small case worth using String Builder, or are there any other reasons to prefer String Builder in these small cases?  It seems like it's a lot of extra typing int he simple case presented above.  I also suspect (though I have not confirmed) that the memory allocations in the simple case are probably not worth it.

Edit:  Suppose that the values being appended aren't known at compile time, I.E. they aren't constants.

Also the example above of ""+12 is a poorly chosen example..  Suppose it was

```
String userGeneratedText  = textInput.getText().toString();
int someVal = intInput.getInt();

String finalVal = userGeneratedText+someVal;
```

Comment: For your first example, why not just use String.valueOf(num)?

Comment: Rule of thumb: in loops, use a `StringBuilder`, because the `+=` operator will compile into creating a new StringBuilder instance in every iteration. For single statements, the `+` operator is just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code is *short* as you shown here:

```
String text = "foo" + 12;
```

The compiler will automatically replace the concatenation to use `StringBuilder`:

```
String text = new StringBuilder().append("foo").append(12).toString();
```

So don't worry about the *inefficiency* of this code, because it will work better than you expect.

For cases when you need to append very large `String`s or you don't know how many objects (Strings, ints, booleans, etc) will you concatenate, use a `StringBuilder` as you do in your second code sample.

Here's a more in depth explanation about how the String concatenation works: http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/09/under-hood-of-java-strings.html

Comment: In that specific example there is no string builder: the value `"12"` will be inlined (at least in "normal" Java - don't know about android).

Comment: This is good info, didn't realize that was what happened.  Could you speak more to the compiled forms of string concatenation?  Very interesting.

Comment: `String s = "aa" + "bb" + "cc" + "dd"` will be compiled simply to `String s = "aabbccdd"`, because such constant value can be resolved it compile time.

Comment: Thanks, made edits to address @Natix comments.  Suppose these values aren't known at compile time?

Comment: Just saw the link.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know! **string** is immutable object. It means that its state cannot be changed, when ever you append value to **string** type then what happened is compiler deletes old one create new one with apended value.

But this is not the case with **StringBuilder**. **StringBuilder** is mutable which means its old value won't be destroyed. Any change/append will be taken place with existing object.

I know I am not covering in depth but this might cause major performance difference.